# Create server login and database user in Azure SQL in C# in a transaction

Tags: c#, sqlclient, azure-sql-server

I am trying to create a login and database user all in the same transaction but I am getting a time out.

First I am opening transaction via TransactionScope and inside I am opening two connections:

First connection is to the master database where I create the login and user for this login.

```
CREATE LOGIN [{UserEmail}] WITH PASSWORD='!mjd25MBC'
CREATE USER [{UserEmail}] FOR LOGIN [{UserEmail}]
```

Second connection is to my user database where I create the user and associate it with previously created login.

```
CREATE USER [{UserEmail}] FOR LOGIN [{UserEmail}]
```

I am getting a time out on this operation.

---

If I ommit user creation on first connection than I will get this error:

> 'SomeLogin' is not a valid login or you do not have permission. Cannot
>   add the principal 'SomeLogin', because it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission.

If I don't use transaction everything is created normally but I don't want to do it because on this operation plenty of things are created and I want the security that a transaction brings.

Doesn't the transaction get promoted to distributed immediately? Is what I am trying to achieve evene possible?

**EDIT:**

This is the C# code used to execute these commands. The using statement initializes the database context and everything executed in that context gets same connection. So the msater context goes to master database and second context goes to user database but with server login which is admin.

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
{
    using (var db = Config.DbController().Activate("Master"))
    {
        var query = new StringBuilder();
        query.AppendLine($"CREATE LOGIN [{UserEmail}] WITH PASSWORD='!mjd25MBC'");
        //query.AppendLine($"CREATE USER [{UserEmail}] FOR LOGIN [{UserEmail}]");
        await new SqlUnlimited(query.ToString()).ExecuteScalarAsync();
    }
    using (var db = Config.DbController().Activate("EkonomeoAdmin"))
    {
        var query = new StringBuilder();
        query.AppendLine($"CREATE USER [{UserEmail}] FOR LOGIN [{UserEmail}]");
        if (UserRole == Role.Worker)
            query.AppendLine($"ALTER ROLE [Ekonomeo_Worker] ADD MEMBER [{UserEmail}]");
        else if (UserRole == Role.Client)
            query.AppendLine($"ALTER ROLE [Ekonomeo_Client] ADD MEMBER [{UserEmail}]");

        await new SqlUnlimited(query.ToString()).ExecuteScalarAsync();
    }
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your C# code?

Comment: @DavidG I have edited the question to include the C# code.

Comment: You don't show the transaction creation, or if the connections are enlisting in existing transactions. Also, a couple of related points about your code. First off, there's not really any benefit to using`StringBuilder` for such a small amount of string manipulation, better to use string interpolation. Secondly, you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks by crafting SQL like this.

Comment: Optimization is the least of my concerns at this point. As for the SQL injections...tehnically you are right.

Comment: It seems, that is because of the async ... maybe you should use a dependent value to control the command-execution order.